# При добавлении margin-top съезжают вверх надписи

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. При добавлении margin-top элементу `container1 ul` съезжают вверх надписи, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Спасибо :)
Видео проблемы: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQAin4cmIhw&feature=youtu.be

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}

#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 27vh;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2vh solid black;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 1vh solid black;
}

.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  width: 11.1vh;
  height: 11vh;
  padding-top: 0.8vh;
  padding-right: 11.5vh;
}

.logo img {
  width: 11.3vh;
  height: 11vh;
  margin: 0vh auto;
  padding-top: 0vh;
}

.main_title {
  padding-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  font-size: 4vh;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0vh 0.4vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
  text-align: center;
}

.subtitle {
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.14vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-right: 0px
}

.second_subtitle {
  font-size: 2.3vh;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background-color: #666666;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  letter-spacing: -0.55px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.top_navigation-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 64px;
}

.top_navigation-menu li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.top_navigation-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.top_navigation-menu li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.top_navigation-menu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2.35vh;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.container1 ul {
  margin-top: 0vh;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="logo.png" alt="ШвейПокров">
    </div>
    <div class="main_title">
      "ШвейПокров"
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Православная швейная мастерская
    </div>
    <div class="second_subtitle">
      доставка по всей России
    </div>
    <ul class="top_navigation-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш `header` имеет относительно-фиксированную высоту(в зависимости от высоты окна браузера юзера). И когда вы добавляете к вашему `top_navigation-menu` `margin` - то скорее всего, выходите за рамки контейнера. Оперируйте не жестко заданным `height`, а свойствами `min-height` и `max-height`. Тогда при добавлении `margin-top` соседние элементы не будут "лезть". 
Т.е. у `header` попробуйте убрать свойство `height`, замените его на `min-height: 27vh` и добавьте желаемый `max-height`(например, `40vh`)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что у вас установлен для header {height: 27vh;} удалите его и все будет ок

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #B63D32;
}
#page-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2vh solid black;
  border-left: 2vh solid black;
  border-right: 2vh solid black;
  border-bottom: 1vh solid black;
}
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.logo {
    width: 11.1vh;
    height: 11vh;
    padding-top: 0.8vh;
    padding-right: 11.5vh;
  }
.logo img {
    width: 11.3vh;
    height: 11vh;
    margin: 0vh auto;
    padding-top: 0vh;
}
.main_title {
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    font-size: 4vh;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0vh 0.4vh rgba(0, 0, 0, .34);
    text-align: center;
}
.subtitle {
  font-size: 2vh;
  font-family: Lobster, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0.14vh;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -3px;
  padding-right: 0px
}
.second_subtitle {
    font-size: 2.3vh;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Impact, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 1px 0.5px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    background-color: #666666;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    letter-spacing: -0.55px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
.top_navigation-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 64px;
}
.top_navigation-menu li {
  padding-left: 20px; 
}
.top_navigation-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
.top_navigation-menu li{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 15%;
    text-align: center;
}
.top_navigation-menu li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.35vh;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
.container1 ul {
  margin-top: 0vh;
  padding-top: 2vh;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="page-wrapper">
  <div id="content-wrapper">
   <header>
     <div class="container1">
      <div class="logo">
       <img src="logo.png" alt="ШвейПокров"> 
      </div>
      <div class="main_title">
       "ШвейПокров"
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        Православная швейная мастерская
      </div>
      <div class="second_subtitle">
       доставка по всей России
      </div>
      <ul class="top_navigation-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: А как тогда определить размер хедеру?

Comment: как написал Klimenkomud ниже в ответе